Slack Notifications Issue
I am using the Flatpak version of Slack on Ubuntu 24.04, but I have an issue with notifications. I only hear the sound, but the notification pop-up doesn't appear.

Do your know for sure the app is updated for use with Ubuntu 24.04?

Would you be opposed to switching to using the native .deb package that's also offered by Slack? I have nothing against Flatpak and far prefer them to Snaps, however none of the "sandboxed" package formats have ever worked for me as well as the actual Debian packages.
I've used the official Slack .deb package for 5+ years and have always gotten the usual notifications. If you're amenable to the switch, I'll gladly post a step-by-step guide to the process as an answer to your question.
